# Hibernate Native Query not populating object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following bean:

```
@Entity(name = "Contact" )
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Members.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    private Members member;

    private Employee employee;
}
```

The following native query is populating the `Contact` member variables, except for the `Employee`. I think `Members` is populated because it is a foreign key, but `Employee` is not. The reason I am using a native query, is to join to the `employee` table and populate the `Employee` object.

```
        String query = "SELECT contact.*, employee.* "
                + "FROM contact "
                + "INNER JOIN members ON members.member_id = contact.member_id "
                + "INNER JOIN employee ON employee.member_id = contact.member_id "
                + "WHERE contact.email = :email";

        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query, Contact.class);
        q.setParameter("email", email);
        contacts = (List<Contact>)q.getResultList();
```

**Question**

How can I get the native query to populate the `Employee`?

Note:

All relationships are one-to-one between contact, member and employee.

Tables

```
**Contact**
contact_id
member_id

**Member**
member_id

**Employee**
employee_id
member_id
```

Comment: You have to use SqlResultsetMapping https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-sql-resultset-mapping

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try